ASP.NET Core 8 web project behaves strangely when playing videos on IIS10
I am hosting an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, frontend is Angular 16. In the test environment, everything works well. In Prod environment, when we would like to play videos, the first video is loading for a few seconds, then it is freezing. After we close it and try to open another video, then screen is freezing and we are unable to touch anything.
When I searched the IIS site logs, I found nothing unusual. I see 206 as response.
When I checked C:\Windows\System32\Logs on http logs, I see an error

Connection_Abandoned_Req_Queue

I checked event logs and I see:

As ISAPI reported an unhealthy condition to its worker process. Therefore, the worker process with process id of '44828' serving application pool 'appname' has requested a recycle.

When I face the exception, I checked the worker processes and I see that the requests still continues, not finished and does not like that going to finish.
I tried these steps to solve the problem:

I compared the test server and prod server components that what is installed - the only difference was .NET Framework 3.5 and I installed it.

Checked .NET Core versions; they are exactly the same, 8.0.1.

Increased ApplicationPool worker process count

Changed Application Pool from "Integrated" to "Classic"

For the Application Pool, I enabled 32-bit applications

Increased virtual memory (this PC > ChangeSettings > Advanced  Settings > Advanced Virtual Memory)

OS updated were waiting so I installed them to avoid any unexpected behaviour

Checked MIME types, change mp4/mpeg

Checked PROD server has hardware problem or something. There is nothing. Everything except this app is working smoothly without harming the system.

I created a process dump but unable to check it unfortunately.


I do not know what more I can do - that's why I would like to ask it here. What can I do to solve this situation?

could you check what is the memory and CPU usage of the machine while you are playing video. what is the idle time out, recycling setting and queue length of the app pool? did you enabled dynamic compression for the site? what is the size of the video? Have you enabled keep alive in the iis? is it possible for you to share the reproducible sample?

I played some video from localhost (IIS Machine) CPU Usage and Memory was normal. Queue length is 1000, recycling setting, auto-recycle happens at 01:58 everyday, on Configuration Changes, Unhealthy ISAPI conditions app pool recycles. There is no limit for virtual memory or something. Dynamic content compression is enabled. Video size is in average 40MB. Keep-Alive is enabled. Idle timeout is 0.

When i try from localhost everything is ok, when i try from internal network everything is ok. When i come from external network, everything is working ok on test IIS, video playing fails on prod IIS. It is loading for a few seconds then freezes. On IIS when i control the requests it stucks at "SendResponse".

Could try these suggestion 1)could you ping your production server and check the network latency2) could you try dealing Http/2 on the production server and test the site3)try to enable caching 4)have tried to test on production with smaller files

could you share your sample code by using which you are rendering video
